# RDLC Export Local Report To CSV

Tags: visual-studio-2010, csv, rdlc

In Visual Sudio 2010 ASPX ReportViewer Control the only export options are: Excel, PDF, and Word.  How can I export the report to CSV.

I understand that SSRS reports can do this, but in my situation this is not a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the data source you can transform the DataSet into CSV and show a link to the user for the download.

You can also add the option CSV on the report viewer export dropdown using jQuery and call the export to CSV when the action is selected.

In this way you "override" the report viewer only for the CSV file format.