# Export RDLC to CSV format

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

From google I got to know that there no way to export to rdlc to csv format by default. I have rdlc reprort which I am using it for WPF application.

Can anybody tell me how RDLC report can be exported to CSV format through programatically?

Any code snippet would help me a lot.

Thanks Inadvance,

Vinay

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151476/rdlc-export-local-report-to-csv

Answer (score 0):

RDLC it's data representive format but Csv it's just a data format. 
How are you going to export first in other if its are absolutly different in core?
Maybe you want ask about exporting to csv from some kind of data? For example from MS SQL table or other data source.